# Android app crashes with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after WIN DEATH

Tags: android, crash, android-asynctask

I defined an AsyncTask and create an instance from inside a MapView class. Everything works perfectly except when Android decides to kill the window, then when I try to re-open the activity the app crashes with a NoClassDefFoundError for my AsyncTask. I also tried making the AsyncTask class static but nothing changed.

I have tested it several times and I'm quite confident that the crash is due to the activity being killed previously.

[Update] I didn't post the stack trace because I saw nothing relevant. I've done some more tests and now I see something in the log that can be a clue:

```
I/ActivityManager(  144): Displayed activity com.myorg.myApp/.MyActivity: 4456 ms (total 4456 ms)
I/dalvikvm( 3413): **Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class** Lcom/myorg/myApp/MyMapView$MyAsyncTask; v=0x0
D/AndroidRuntime( 3413): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 3413): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207e8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myorg.myApp.MyMapView$MyAsyncTask
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413):    at com.myorg.myApp.MyMapView$4.run(MyMapView.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3413):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The line: **I/dalvikvm( 3413): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class**
Makes me think that it comes from a previous error but I see no other stack traces in the log or errors reported.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code as well the stack trace causing the crash.  It will be hard to help you without that.

Comment: I solved the problem.
I was creating an AsyncTask inside a runnable posted to a handler. I have had no problem with this before and I'm still using it in some places but, for some reason, when it was called from the onCreate method of my Activity, the AsyncTask failed after a WIN DEATH (but no error was reported on the log) and the following AsyncTasks where rejected. If I, instead, don't use the handler and create the AsyncTask directly, everything works, even some AsyncTasks which are created after and posted to a handler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that problem in UI Thread

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            asynTask = new LoadWebAsynTask();
            asynTask.execute();
        }
    });
```

Comment: A bit late but this is actually the solution. I can't provide the code because I don't have access to it anymore. To complete this response, I recommend to read the "Threading rules" section in the [AsyncTask reference documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'd need a stack trace to be sure, but I think your problem is similar to the one described [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968744/getting-noclassdeffounderror-android-os-asynctask).

It's not necessarily that the classloader can't find your AsyncTask class - it's that some error is thrown during the loading of the class, or during the startup of the Thread backing the AsyncTask that's preventing the classloader from loading the class.

I'd guess the WIN DEATH is causing some strange internal state that's not being checked for and is throwing the error.