# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError android.os.AsyncTask

Tags: android

when i reboot device NoClassDefFoundError when Android app is launched after a crash.[image]

Comment: On Android 4.0 is working fine.but devices with Android Version 2.3 getting this exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting NoClassDefFoundError: android.os.AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968744/getting-noclassdeffounderror-android-os-asynctask)