# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.os.AsyncTask caused by AdMob / Google Play Services?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, admob

Since November 21, 2014 I am receiving hundreds of crash reports with the stack below.

The crash occurs only on API Level 10 devices (the app supports 9+)

The very same version of the app had been running fine over several weeks before the crashes started. This makes me think that the problem is caused by some over-the-air update that was pushed to Android 2.3 devices recently.

I use AdMob mediation (which is now part of the Google Play Services library) and several other ad network SDKs in my app.

I suspect the Google Play Services library to be causing the crash, as it is the only part of the app that, to my knowledge, is likely to be updated over-the-air (and this would not be the first time a buggy update causes crashes).

Is it possible, as mentioned by the OPs answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968744/getting-noclassdeffounderror-android-os-asynctask/7233642#comment42810535_7233642), that an uncaught exception triggered inside the thread created by AdMob to display banner ads **might put the whole process in a state where it is not able to create new instances of classes anymore?**

Has anybody been suffering from a similar issue recently?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myapp.MyClassExtendingAsyncTask
at com.myapp.x.run(SourceFile:417)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3859)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:647)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.MyClassExtendingAsyncTask in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.myapp-1.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
... 10 more
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate and start com.myapp.MyClassExtendingAsyncTask from?

Comment: @William this custom AsyncTask is instantiated and run from the UI thread. Its purpose is pretty common: fetch data online asynchronously.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, looks like it is a problem with one of the versions of Google play Services.
See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81083

Looks like a work around might be to add the following to your `Application#onCreate()`:

```
package acme.com.myAppName;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        // begin add
        try {
            Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
        } catch(Throwable ignore) {
        }
        // end add

        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

NB don't forget to configure your Application class in your `AndroidManifest.xml` (if you haven't already).

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="acme.com.myAppName.MyApplication" >
...
</application>
```

Comment: (I'm the one who filed bug 81083) I have implemented this workaround and it seems to have fixed the issue on all 2.3.x devices.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on the answer above, as I didn't know what the Application#onCreate() was and hadn't already implement one in my app.
What I did was create a new Class in my app with the following:

```
package acme.com.myAppName;

import android.app.Application;

public class myApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
        }
        catch(Throwable ignore){}

        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Then I updated my AndroidManifest.xml file with `android:name="acme.com.myAppName.myApplication"` to use the `myApplication` class, like so:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="acme.com.myAppName.myApplication" >
...
</application>
```

Comment: Hi James, Is this solved your crash? I also have the same problem in app like I dont have Application class.

Comment: @Programmer It seems to have solved it!  Since deploying live I've not had anymore crashes with the AsyncTask error.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, since 23/11 I got about 1500 ClassNotFoundException errors on 2.x clients, with an increasing trend.
The app was not updated for months, so I agree on your hypothesis about the google play services ota update

Comment: Admob, DFP and Facebook Audience, both for banner and for interstitial.

Answer (score 0):

I surrounded my `adview.loadAd(adrequest);` with a try catch block and this has solved my issue.

Here is the code snippet :

```
    try
    {
    adview.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
    catch(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ncdfe)
    {
        ncdfe.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("AD ERROR", "ERROR LOADING AD");
    }
```