# Android Proguard - keep class and methods

Tags: java, android, proguard

I need to make sure the method

```
java.lang.String -> isEmpty()
```

Is present in the compiled code.

Will Proguard keep this method if it is referenced somewhere in my code? Or is it better to include

```
-keep class java.lang.String { *; }
```

Into Proguard configuration file?

I'm asking because to fix [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27239869) this code is used:

```
    try {
          Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");              
    }
    catch(Throwable ignore) {}
```

Instead of adding this to Proguard:

```
-keep class android.os.AsyncTask { *; }
```

Comment: Proguard is only going to touch classes in your project, not classes that are part of the platform, such as AsyncTask and String. So this doesn't sound like a Proguard problem.  You might want to try posting your code and full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referencing that method in your code, it should be kept by Proguard. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/proguard.html):

> The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by
>   removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with
>   semantically obscure names

So if the code is being used, there's no reason why Proguard would remove it.