# android admob error changing activity with asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, admob

I have 2 activities (ListActivity and ContactsActivity)

Both works perfectly without Admob.

But if I have admob in ListActivity, it works perfectly but when I click a button to change to ContactsActivity (it have an AsyncTask function to get all contacts from mobile) the application exploits with this error:

[image]

If anyone can help me how to solve this problem or telling other options do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in line 98 of ContactActivity? Can you post the java code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting NoClassDefFoundError: android.os.AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968744/getting-noclassdeffounderror-android-os-asynctask)

Answer (score 0):

Loading of Ads might be throwing any un-handled exception. Try surrounding the ads-loading code in try-catch. Or paste the code in here.

Edit: If you are loading ads in the AsyncTask, remove it from there. Call the loading of ad after loading the contacts list.

Like:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new LoadContactsList();
        ...

        Method to load your ads;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that adding the following code in my initial Activity solves the problem:

```
try {
      Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
}
catch(Throwable ignore) {}
```